# How do i find over 200K differently named files and output

Tags: scripting, grep, find

We have a SAN with a lot (over 5 million) of files. Because of some freak mistake from a developer script, some files have been deleted and we now have to figure out which files got deleted.

Now, I do have a list with the filenames (from our database) that need to be checked, which looks like this:

```
49
50
51
52
```

I have figured out how I can use the `find` command to do this for single and multiple files, as follows:

```
find /mnt/SAN/documents/ -type f -name"92441_1"
```

This works, but I cannot use this command with over 200K+ files to check. So I am wondering if anyone knows a way to get the `find` command to take input from my file, or if there is another command I can use to get this done.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like (assuming GNU tools):

```
find /mnt/SAN/documents -type f -print0 | awk -F / '
  NR == FNR{check[$0]; next}
  $NF in check {print "found:", $0; delete check[$NF]}
  END {
    for (i in check)
      print "Not found:", i
  }' filename.list RS='\0' -
```

Which would find one occurrence for each filename in `filename.list`.

Or to report all occurrences:

```
find /mnt/SAN/documents -type f -print0 | awk -F / '
  NR == FNR{check[$0]; notfound[$0]; next}
  $NF in check {print "found:", $0; delete notfound[$NF]}
  END {
    for (i in notfound)
      print "Not found:", i
  }' filename.list RS='\0' -
```

Comment: i have tried using this in a testing enviroment with a couple of numbers of files that i know are there, but somehow they are all returning to `Not found: [number]`, so it is taking input from the filename.list. i am however not sure what i am doing wrong here. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Use something like

```
find /mnt/SAN/documents/ -type f | perl -ple 's,^.*/,,' > files_currently_present
```

to generate a list of files currently on disc, without paths and then use

```
comm -2 -3 filelist_from database files_currently_present
```

to compare it to the list from your backup and generate a list of mssing files.

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way is to read the file names from your file using a shell loop and then run multiple `find` commands in the background:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
    find /mnt/SAN/documents/ -type f -name "$file" &
done < fileList.txt > foundFiles.txt
```

That, however, will launch 200K+ instances of `find` and will probably bring your machine to its knees. A better approach would be to build a complex `find` command, giving it each file name:

```
$ printf 'find /mnt/SAN/documents/ -type f '; while IFS= read -r file; do printf -- '-name "%s" -o ' "$file"; done < fileList.txt | sed 's/-o $/\n/'
find /mnt/SAN/documents/ -type f -name "49" -o -name "50" -o -name "51" -o -name "52"
```

You can then run the command itself either by copy/pasting it or with:

```
eval $(printf 'find /mnt/SAN/documents/ -type f '; \
    while IFS= read -r file; do 
        printf -- '-name "%s" -o ' "$file"; done < fileList.txt | 
            sed 's/-o $/\n/')
```

However, this will also break if you have too many files, so you'll want to run it in batches:

```
for i in $(seq 1 100 $(wc -l < fileList.txt)); do 
    k=$((i+100)); 
    printf 'find /mnt/SAN/documents/ -type f '; 
    sed -n "$i,${k}p" fileList.txt | 
    while IFS= read -r file; do 
        printf -- '-name "%s" -o ' "$file"; 
    done  | sed 's/-o $/\n/';   
done
```

That will create separate `find` commands for each batch of 100 files in your list which you can execute with `eval` as shown above, or just save in a file and run the file:

```
for i in $(seq 1 100 $(wc -l < fileList.txt)); do 
    k=$((i+100)); 
    printf 'find /mnt/SAN/documents/ -type f '; 
    sed -n "$i,${k}p" fileList.txt | 
    while IFS= read -r file; do 
        printf -- '-name "%s" -o ' "$file"; 
    done  | sed 's/-o $/\n/';   
done > script.sh && bash script.sh > foundFiles.txt
```

---

Note that [Stéphane's approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/286681/22222), starting with existing files and checking which are missing would almost certainly be better here (unless the existing files are more than the missing ones). In a similar vein, you could first build a list of all existing files and then use `comm` to compare that to the list of target files (since you say you have a list of files, I will assume that your file names will never contain newline characters):

```
find /mnt/SAN/documents/ -type f | sort > found
comm -13 <(sort found) <(sort fileList.txt)
```

The `comm` command will print all lines that are in `fileList.txt` but not in `found`.

Answer (score -1):

It is very time consuming to run find against every file name in 200K+files. If I were you , I would run `find ${FILESROOT}  > /tmp/SANfiles` then

```
for filename in $(cat my_database_files)
do
  grep "${filename}" /tmp/SANfiles > /dev/null; r=${?}
  if [ ${r} -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo ${filename} >> /tmp/existing_files
  else
    echo ${filename} >> /tmp/missing_files
  fi
done
```

depending on how the file names in your database is formatted, you might want to modify the variable name in the for loop, but I think you've got the gist of my idea.

Comment: Never iterate over a list of file names with a `for` loop (commonly known as [Bash Pitfall #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)). This will break if any of the file names contains a space or a globbing character.